# Renormalization group trigonometric integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I am going through Wen's QFT of many-body systems, namely the section on the renormalization of non-compact clock model. He has a calculation there of a particular integral over the fast fields that I just cannot figure out: [image]

Here $K(x)$ is the propagator of the fast fields, with a regularizer $0^+$, which can be inferred from the second equality. I got to the first expression on the second line, with only the angular integral left, and I can't figure out how to get to the final result. This line seems to imply:

$$\int d\theta \, \frac{1}{(\cos \theta + i 0^+)^4} = 8 \pi$$

And I don't know how to get that. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which page? Which eq?

Comment: @Qmechanic Bottom of page 112, the equation is unnumbered